# How can I crack WPA2 hash with some limitations?

Tags: password-cracking, wpa2, hashcat

I want to crack an 8 character password, but I know this password **doesn't** contain **more than** 4 symbols, 4 uppercase letters, 4 lowercase letters and 4 numbers, and it contains **at least** 2 symbols, 2 uppercase letters, 2 lowercase letters and 2 numbers.

The character set I'm using is 94 (brute-force) characters long. My PC has a rate of 70MH/s (roughly 70 000 000/s) with an GTX1660 Ti using hashcat. This means that I would take around 2 years and 9 months to reach the most unlucky end (keyspace).

With these limits, the time might decrease significantly, but how can I set such limits in hashcat (how do I create such mask)?
Also, how can I calculate it's time?

Comment: The "how much time" bit is just a pure math question. Not really a security question.

Comment: hashcat does not have this kind of mask. You are looking for a combination with requirements. That's not a "mask". To do what you want, it would have to generate the string, then reject non-compliant strings. You can do that by creating a list generator that creates the full list for you. hashcat won't do it.

Comment: It seems I need to create a custom dictionary file for this. How can I create such dictionary with these limits?

Comment: That is a programming question. The linked question shows one way to approach it.